# $\ell^0$ and $\ell^{\infty}$ norms

Tags: normed-spaces

Let $x \in S^{n-1}$ and such that its coordinates $|x_1|\geq \cdots \geq |x_n|$.

Under which condition on $\|x\|_0$ the following inequality is true that $$\|x\|_{\infty}\leq \frac{1}{\sqrt {\|x\|_0}}\quad ?$$

Comment: Sorry but what is $\|x\|_0$?

Comment: $\|x\|_0$ is a cardinality of a support of $x$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Thanks.

Comment: Surely you can find a vector in $S^1$ with two non-zero entries the first of which is as close to $1$ as you wish.

Comment: @ Martin: Sorry I stated my question incorrectely. I ment is it always tru? or How to prove it?

Comment: Why would you expect this to be true? Just take a vector on $S^{n-1}$ very close to $(1,0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: @Martin: Aha I see. Thank you. I wanted condition on $\|x\|_0$ such that it would be true.